How to fully reset a system audio configuration in Ubuntu Studio 24.04?
This mess is largely a snowball of choices after trying to figure out a small problem, where each attempt to fix it made it worse. I started from upgrading pipewire to an upstream PPA in the hopes of getting more stability, then downgrading it, then removing configs in /etc/pipewire and elsewhere. I tried purging pipewire* and wireplumber* and reinstalling them.
Results of alsamixer :
[E] pw.loop [loop.c:67 pw_loop_new()] 0x55daf24d8820: can't make support.system handle: 
No such file or directory  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Results of aplay -D pipewire :
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:339:(snd_dlobj_cache_get0) 
Cannot open shared library libasound_module_pcm_pipewire.so (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pipewire.so: undefined symbol: 
pw_stream_get_nsec) aplay: main:834: audio open error: 
No such device or address

Results of pipewire :
[E] pw.loop [loop.c:67 pw_loop_new()] 0x5a5ef46b0a80: can't make support.system handle: 
No such file or directory
[E] default [pipewire.c:93 main()] failed to create main-loop: 
No such file or directory

Results of wireplumber :
W 13:25:29.676191            pw.loop ../pipewire/src/pipewire/loop.c:67:pw_loop_new: 
0x581990edcaa0: can't make support.system handle: 
No such file or directory
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Some more details:

No hw issues. aplay -l lists devices. Audio was working fine up until this point.
alsamixer runs without error if pipewire is removed.
pipewire packages are currently 1.0.5-1, rolled back from 1.0.7-3
No broken packages.

Update:
I ran strace on pipewire and found it was looking for libraries in /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ instead of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ There were a few 0-byte files there. I replaced the folders with symlinks.
That stopped the pw_loop_new() errors. The pipewire services are active now, but doing anything with them causes them to hang. aplay -D pipewire still gives the same error.

Turns it it wasn't just a couple stray libraries that were in /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
pipewire --version demonstrated that compiled and linked versions were different for pipewire.
ldd /usr/bin/pipewire revealed the second libpipewire-0.3.so.0 in the same place.
Cleaning out the directory there seems to have restored my audio to working condition.
